# how to override devise security extension PasswordExpiredController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to override show logic in order to permit change password not only if it  is expired, but some days earlier. I need to modify or replace this `before_filter logic`

```
def skip_password_change
    return if !resource.nil? && resource.need_change_password?
    redirect_to :root
end
```

I want to make my controller like this:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordExpiredController
    # ...
    def skip_password_change
        return if !resource.nil? && (resource.need_change_password? || ... )
        redirect_to :root
    end
end
```

How to achieve my goal?

**UPD:**
all answers below are kind of right, I missed one thing - my custom controller was placed inside controllers/admin directory, so I should name it Admin::CustomPasswordExpiredController, but I missed Namespace prefix Admin and rails fell into circular dependency.

Comment: plz post your error stack trace

Comment: could not reproduce error, I'll change question simply to - "how to...", as I'm not shure If it right to use devise_for here, because security_extension_gem patches routes not using devise_for method: https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension/blob/b2ee978af7d49f0fb0e7271c6ac074dfb4d39353/lib/devise_security_extension/routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend devise controller with your custom controller:

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: 'custom_passwords' }

# app/controllers/custom_passwords_controller.rb
class CustomPasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def edit
    resource = resource_class.new
    return unless resource.need_change_password? # your middleware logic here
    super
  end
end
```

More facilities can be found in devise [PasswordsController documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/PasswordsController) (by clicking "View source")

Answer (score 1):

You can try this workaround, first skip the default `before_action` for `skip_password_change` method, then add a custom method to wrap it in a condition. Try this

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordExpiredController
  skip_before_action :skip_password_change, only: :show
  before_action :skip_password_change_show, only: :show

  def skip_password_change_show
    return if !resource.nil? && (resource.need_change_password? || #yourcondition )
    redirect_to :root
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The question was: How to make app to use my custom PasswordsController instead of Devise::PasswordExpiredController, which is introduced by devise_security_extensions gem

Answer (score 1):

Go to your routes file and overwrite the controller methods there.

Something like `devise_for :users, controllers: {x: 'y'}` where x is the name of the controller from devise that you want to overwrite and y is the name of your custom controller you want to overwrite with